# Scale ssh forwarded graphical interface

Tags: ssh, xforwarding

I am running gnome on top of archlinux on a samsung ultrabook which display is hidpi. Gnome supports hidpi quite well actually, and apart some applications that ignore the system font settings or the UI scaling I must say I am quite satisfied with the results.

The problems begin when I need to connect to a remote server and launch some CAD software installed on it. Unfortunately the server is unaware of my DPI so the windows on my laptop are rendered with what I suppose to be a somewhat standard DPI, thus making text barely legible.

I have searched a bit through ssh manual but did not find anything about that, infact I suspect it is something that must happen on another layer. Unfortunately changing things on the server is not an option since it is not possible to apply such a setting for me only and there are several other users.

When I ran `man ssh` I was hoping for something like

```
ssh -CY --virt-res=1920x1080 vladimir@example.com
```

but unfortunately that is not so.

Has anybody any suggestion?

Comment: SSH merely forwards X traffic, it doesn't understand the X protocol, so a concept like DPI doesn't apply. The application will receive the same DPI information as if it was running locally. If it doesn't scale its fonts automatically the way you want, change the font in the application.

Comment: thanks @Gilles. Unfortunately changing the application fonts, while possible, does not work well but that's an application issue of course. I will look further into it keeping your insight in mind and come back if I can get it to work